# Any way to fix the conflict between id and name on form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'm doing a webserver with jsp, i'm validating the log in and i found a conflict.

I got:

```
<form action="Autenticacion" method="POST" class="form">
        <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="loginbutton" name="login" >Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="usuario_nuevo">Nuevo Usuario</button>
</form>
```

On the button properties, i really need id and name.

id = Because it calls a JS who animates the  tag. 
name = Because do the validation on webservice.

My code on js is:

```
 $(".loginbutton").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

 $('form').fadeOut(500);
 $('.wrapper').addClass('form-success');});
```

This calls another css, now i want to fix this, because i need to use both, the first "id" for the animation and then "name" for the validation and send to another jsp page (that already got coded and work).

EDIT 1: Already added the noconflict on Jquery, but only do the validation, not the id animation.

EDIT 2: changed id for class

Comment: If its classic script conflict try adding this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @KamilBogumił Already added the noconflict, but only do the validation and not the animation

Comment: I didn't get it, did you get error on this line - $("#login").click(function(event){event.preventDefault();

Comment: @totaloverdose I don't get any error. I just want the animation first and then redirect to other page. (the validation work perfectly)

Comment: Try to change jquery selector, you can use class name as selector like $('.login').click by adding class="login" in button tag

Comment: @totaloverdose Already did that, the only thing that probably work is doing the call of the validation from the js...

Comment: ok, is animation work if you didn't submit the form?

Comment: Post error from console.log plz.

Comment: @totaloverdose If i delete the id and leave only name="login", it works. And the same way if i delete name and leave id. That's the problem

Comment: add one more line "$('form').submit();" after 
$('.wrapper').addClass('form-success') in your code.

Comment: What kind of event does validation use. .click?

Comment: @totaloverdose i tried that, almost worked, but it stays on the same page.

Comment: recheck your action attribute of from tag, I added code in answer working for me.

Comment: @KamilBogumił I just looked the console and as i see. 

POST 
http://localhost:8080/ClienteVuelo/Autenticacion [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 108ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/ClienteVuelo/login.jsp [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/ClienteVuelo/css/style.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET 
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

First do the autentication, then calls the "index.jsp" and finally calls the style. It must call the style first and then the index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is works for me is -

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#page').animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

It look like you didn't submit form after fadeout. 
Add one more line 
"$('form').submit();" after $('.wrapper').addClass('form-success') in your code.

Comment: Yes, finally! idk how it worked this time, i tried the first time you said it. But this time i did as a "id" not as a class. Tyvm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could change the id to whatever you want, and instead adding the click event with jQuery('#login').click(), you could use jQuery('.loginButton').click(). Don't forget to add the loginButton class for the button.